# Get attribute is None in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get my API key from the website below, but am having issues locating the key within the HTML. `api_key` below comes up `Null` every time I run the code, even though I've followed other examples explicitly. Is the issue with the parser I'm using?

```
site_url = "https://developer.forecast.io/"
site_html = urllib2.urlopen(site_url).read()
site_soup = BeautifulSoup(site_html,"html.parser")

api_key = site_soup.find("input",{"id":"api_key"})
```

Edit: This is the HTML I'm looking at:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span10" id="api_keys">
    <div class="well">
      <h2>API Key</h2>
        <span class="input-append">
          <input id="api_key" type="text" value="47580427a2916a5059085b6a65fc3990"
```

Comment: That is the HTML you see in the browser, correct? Are you logged in? When I am not logged in, I don't see an `input` anywhere on that page.

Comment: I see it in the browser, that's right. I am logged in. Will I have to log in with python and then scrape it?

Comment: And you are logged in, right? What html does your `site_html` variable contain? It looks like you'll need to log in to get the input form you mention

Comment: Yes, I am logged in. The site_html doesn't contain `input`, though: I get `-1` when I try `site_html.find("input")`